# Flink Jdbc sink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I have created an application where I read data from Kinesis streams and sink the data into mysql table.

I tried to load test the app. For 100k entries it takes more than 3 hours. Any suggestion why it's happening so slow. One more thing is the primary key of my table consist of 7 columns.

I am using hibernate to store POJOs directly into database.

code :

```
public class JDBCSink extends RichSinkFunction<CompetitorConfig> {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistry;
    private Session session;
    private  String username;
    private  String password;
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CompetitorConfigJDBCSink.class);

    public JDBCSink(String user, String pass) {
        username = user;
        password = pass;
    }

    public static void configureHibernateUtil(String username, String password) {
        try {

            Properties prop= new Properties();
            prop.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
            prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "url");
            prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", username);
            prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password);
            org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configuration = new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration().addProperties(prop);
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(CompetitorConfig.class);
            serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry.build());
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
             throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {

        configureHibernateUtil(username,password);
        this.session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void invoke(CompetitorConfig value) throws Exception {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.merge(value);
            session.flush();

        } catch (Exception e) {
             throw e;
        } finally {
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
           this.session.close();
            sessionFactory.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is slow because you writing each record individually, wrapped in its own transaction. A high performance database sink will do buffered, bulk writes, and commit transactions as part of checkpointing.

If you need exactly once guarantees and can be satisfied with upsert semantics, you can use FLINK's existing JDBC sink. If you require two-phase commit, that's already been merged to master, and will be included in Flink 1.13. See [FLINK-15578](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-15578).

Update:

There's no standard SQL syntax for an upsert; you'll need to figure out if and how your database supports this. For example:

MySQL:

```sql
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
```

PostgreSQL:

```sql
INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE SET ...
```

For what it's worth, applications like this are generally easier to implement using Flink SQL. In that case you would use the [Kinesis table connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connectors/kinesis.html) together with the [JDBC table connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connectors/jdbc.html).

Comment: Hi @David I am using Flink 1.11 and I couldn't find any support for storing POJOs directly into the JDBC. It would be great of you guide me towards correct way of doing the same.

Comment: What did you try? Did you look at https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/connectors/jdbc.html ?

Comment: I didn't try this because we need to manually write query. I'll try this. Can you tell how we achieve upsert semantics using such query.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.